# How to decrypt RSA encrypted string in c# while it was encrypted in GO language. Error occurred while decoding OAEP padding

Tags: c#, go, encryption, rsa, public-key-encryption

I have an application running on c# and another server application in go. I need to implement secure communication using rsa.

What i'am doing is I've initialized the RSA provider in my C# application and generated public key to extract Modulus and Exponent. Then concatenated the modulus (Hexadecimal) and exponent (int) and converted this string to Base64 string, send it to a GO endpoint.

Here is C# code snippet

```
public string ConvertToPublicKey()
    {
        CspParameters rsaParameters = GetCspParameters();
        RSACryptoServiceProvider provider = newRSACryptoServiceProvider(rsaParameters);
        string paramsXml = RsaProvider.ToXmlString(false);

        XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Parse(paramsXml);
        string modulus = xDocument.Descendants().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Modulus")?.Value ?? string.Empty;
        string exponent = xDocument.Descendants().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Exponent")?.Value ?? string.Empty;
        byte[] base64BytesOfModulus = Convert.FromBase64String(modulus);
        string hexaDecimalofModulus = BitConverter.ToString(base64BytesOfModulus).Replace("-", string.Empty);
        byte[] base64BytesOfExponent = Convert.FromBase64String(exponent);
        string hexadecimalOfExponent = BitConverter.ToString(base64BytesOfExponent).Replace("-", string.Empty);
        int intOfExponent = Convert.ToInt32(hexadecimalOfExponent, 16);
        byte[] publicKey = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{hexaDecimalofModulus};{intOfExponent}");
        return Convert.ToBase64String(publicKey);
    }

    private static CspParameters GetCspParameters()
    {
        const string containerName = "KeyContainer";
        return new CspParameters
        {
            KeyContainerName = containerName,
            Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseMachineKeyStore
        };
    }
```

At Go endpoint I received public key and modulus correctly. Then I encrypted the message using public key and sent it back to c# application in response after converting encrypted message byte[] to base64.

Here is GO code snippet

```
func GetLicenseInfo(responseWriter http.ResponseWriter,request*http.Request) 
    {
    encryptionKey := request.Header.Get("Authorization")
    var decodedStringBytes, errors = b64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(encryptionKey)
    if errors == nil {
        var decodedString = string(decodedStringBytes)
        result := strings.Split(decodedString, ";")
        modulus := new(big.Int)
        modulus.SetString(result[0], 16)
        exponent, exponentErrors := strconv.Atoi(result[1])
        if exponentErrors == nil {
            var someInfo = utils.GetInfo()
            var InfoInJson = ToJson(someInfo)
            publicKey := &rsa.PublicKey{N: modulus, E: exponent}
            var encryptedMessage, err = rsa.EncryptOAEP(sha256.New(),rand.Reader, publicKey,[]byte(InfoInJson), []byte(""))
            var response = b64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(encryptedMessage)
            if err == nil {
                json.NewEncoder(responseWriter).Encode(response)
            }
        }

    }
}

func ToJson(model InfoModel) string {
    InfoInJson, errors := json.Marshal(model)
    if errors != nil {
        panic("An error occurred while serializing the response")
    }
    return string(InfoInJson)
}
```

When i received the response back in Base64 string i converted it to `Byte[]` and tried decrypting that with same instance of `RSACryptoServiceProvider` then it throws the following exception

> Error occurred while decoding OAEP padding.

any help?

**UPDATE**
for example here is the base64 string that i received in GO

> QUQ2NDlFRTlCQTA3Q0IxNEI1MTNDMzczQzBBMjNBOEQyMDI5MkVGQTBFMjgyNUIyMEEyMzM1MEE3OTUyNjgyQ0Y3MEFBQjJBMTZGMzQyNTM4MkU2RDZBRjU5M0IxRTI2MTE0OEIyQkFFRTY3MUVDMTQ1NDk1NjBDRkNEQUNCQzI3RUUxNDRFODZDQUI4RDBDOUY2OENBNTUwNUMxQjZGQkVBQjQ0MTlBMjg3RDhBRjgxRDUyREY3MEM0RDZDQTA5MkREMzk5Q0NEODU5Q0FGQzAzQ0JEQ0JBQzgwOTg3NDY0NThBMkY4NEREOTc1QjU5QTJBMUNBNzQxQTBDNkQ2RDs2NTUzNw==

and here is what my GO app sent back

> QuWpWdEPSJR+l9UJTkh+heJJ/NpPwhz/hVVu1VdKYdz37YGWWdKTj7Fc5lZ3A8p1WjtC4F+yieZCz0tEatCqTpRmm9g6Oioyjbtr9qGTxO/PE+GA33YyBe6nmMRe674SPePx/fg6l3nnfSZ4/+iLCV4bNgyNqFHCaXc7H4Snms8=

**UPDATE 2**
I've updated the code snippet and included the data types and here is the part that dscrypts the content received from GO end point

```
public byte[] Decrypt(byte[] encryptedData, RSAParameters rsaParameters)
    {
        RsaProvider.ImportParameters(rsaParameters);
        return RsaProvider.Decrypt(encryptedData, true);
    }
```

i receive a base64 string then i convert to byte[] using this

```
byte[] b = Convert.FromBase64String(responseString); byte[] decryptedBytes=crypto.Decrypt(b, crypto.RsaProvider.ExportParameters(false));
```

crypto is the instance of the class that contains decryption logic,instacne of `RSACryptoServiceProvider` and that method(ConvertToPublicKey) given above returning the public key

Comment: I'd usually recommend that you implement the entire cleartext -> encryption -> ciphertext -> decryption -> cleartext path in both languages. That way you can *directly* compare the outputs that you're generating at each stage and ensure they match. Once you have two matching implementations, it then becomes *significantly* easier to pick a point where you transition from one to the other.

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code? How about printing the actual values used for encryption/decryption to make sure the problem isn't in your serialization?

Comment: yes I did I'm receiving the correct values in GO endpoint, but I'm not sure if encryption in GO being done follows the same implementation for RSA as C# does or is a there issue in my implementation on C# side

Comment: We can't tell either. To figure out exactly how each library works, write unit tests in both languages with hard-coded inputs and expected outputs. Then build up from there. As is, the intent of your code is not clear.

Comment: @Marc I've verified serialization part. `json.NewEncoder(responseWriter).Encode(response)` encrypted uint8 byte array was obtained in c# in `byte[]` as it was in go.

Comment: Fair enough. But for our sake, please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your question is specifically about C# vs Go encryption/decryption. Provide the smallest sample code that shows problems. This will make your question much clearer and useful for other people having the same issue.

Comment: @MarcI just added the sample output for both ends

Comment: This is neither minimal (way too much code that has nothing to do with your question), complete (lots of missing data types), nor verifiable (again, too many missing type declarations, we can't run this). You're also not showing the C# decryption which is about half of your question.

Comment: @MarcI just updated the question, adding the parts that you mentioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After addressing comments by @bartonjs I've also changed response response from go to

```
var encryptedMessage, err = rsa.EncryptOAEP(sha256.New(), rand.Reader, publicKey, []byte(licenseInformationJson), []byte(""))
if err == nil {
    responseWriter.Write([]byte(encryptedMessage))
}
```

Notice `[]byte(encryptedMessage)` byte stream sent from `go` to `c#` is slightly changed because `encryptedMessage` is `[]unint8`. so you need to typecast `encryptedMessage` to `[]byte` so that values are correctly mapped in c#.

Answer (score 2):

In go you have

```
var encryptedMessage, err = rsa.EncryptOAEP(sha256.New(), ...
```

Which I'll go ahead and assume is OAEP with SHA-2-256.

In C# you have

```
return RsaProvider.Decrypt(encryptedData, true);
```

Which is OAEP with SHA-1.

You need to abandon RSACryptoServiceProvider.  If you switch to RSACng you can then decrypt it with

```
using (RSA rsa = new RSACng())
{
    rsa.ImportParameters(rsaParameters);
    return rsa.Decrypt(encryptedData, RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA256);
}
```

---

And while I'm here:

In `ConvertToPublicKey` you export the XML, parse the XML, and turn it into byte arrays.  Why not just call `ExportParameters(false)` and extract the Modulus and Exponent byte arrays directly?

Comment: let me try that

Comment: using RSACng did help me but the thing I was missing was cast as @Talha Junaid mentioned.thanks anyways